# What could generate bad dictionary pointers?

Tags: errors, pdftex

What could cause [my PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j7mq9rbk7ehuol9/Notes.pdf?dl=0) to have bad object references in its Page resources dictionary (`trailer/Root/Pages/Kids/0/Resources`). Instead of simply omitting unused resources, like ColorSpace and ExtGState, I have some that are instead pointing to Free (undefined objects).

Is there a likely culprit in the typical `pdftex` toolchain, or packages that are known to produce this error?

---

pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)

Comment: I've obtained your file and saved it on my disk, viewed it with `Adobe Reader` on Linux and there are no error messages

Comment: Can you include the complete .tex source of your file in the question, not just a link to the PDF?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: It won't be much help. It involves a sprawling mess of custom packages. For that reason I'm looking for a place to start narrowing the search: anything that's a likely culprit of the observed flaw.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Many readers don't have trouble with the file, others do. But the question is not whether people have trouble viewing it, it's what are (if any) likely LaTeX producers of the observed flaw in the file (whether a given reader trips over it or not). I'm looking for some help narrowing my search through the code that generates the file.

Comment: @orome: That requires the code here ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Are you saying the answer to *this* question is "no" (and therefore that one would need code to determine what is causing the glitches); or are you saying something else?

Comment: It is of course not impossible that someone will give you useful advice simply for the description you've provided; but it is no less likely that no one will be able to name the specific package(s) at issue. (In fact, the latter is probably the more likely outcome.) But it is not actually hard to create a MWE that reproduces the error for a 'sprawling mess of custom packages', just time-consuming. The place to start is by eliminating *all* custom packages, and then slowly adding them back in.

Comment: @jon: Maybe the question isn't clear. Again, if the answer is "no" then there's a separate question to be asked (or a redo of this one) that takes the approach you suggest. But that's a *different question*. *This question* is about whether the flaw in the file is one that people recognize, and if so, whether there's anything general that can be said about the likely source (e.g., it is common and could come from anything, or it's rare and comes from using feature X or package Y). An answer to that question will save everyone time in the follow up (both creating it and answering it).

Comment: The answer can hardly ever be 'no', though, can it? One would need to have pretty solid knowledge of all(?) LaTeX packages to answer 'no'. So really, you're hoping for someone to say 'yes' *and* for it to be in relation to a package you just so happen to be using (because no one knows what you are actually doing). So, I agree: you're hoping to get lucky. The other comments are trying to help you problem-solve, which, as you know, can be time-consuming. (For the record, if I had a suggestion, I would've made it. But since I don't, I'm trying to help you solve your problem.)

Comment: @jon Yes. This is about seeing if we can all save a lot of time with a “yes”. Let’s give that a chance, shall we.

Comment: @orome: I wrote (in short): We need some code in order to see why there are glitches. At the moment, there is a  PDF only.

Comment: Sure, as you wish. It's not like I voted to close. I was just trying to explain why you were getting comments about seeing some code (and why I agreed with them). However, I don't think this is about us 'all' saving time: it is about you hoping to save your own time. I understand the desire, but no one else's time is saved by you asking an extremely specific and yet completely untestable question unless they choose to ignore the question.